# Symfony2 Best Practices Editable text sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working on a symfony2 project using sonata admin bundle. I have some editable text on my website like "presentation" "actually" etc...

I found a solution but it does not feel like its the good way to do.

I've created an Entity EditableText where I map a key with a content like :

key => "presentation"
content => "this is my presentation"

and I do the same for all of my EditableText.

Doing it this way leads me to a list of EditableText in my sonata admin bundle which is not "user friendly" for a non tech guy. If he removes a row, the website can't find the content ... etc ...

I would like to have in sonata a field where the user can edit each texts somewhere, but cannot modify they key or delete a row or something.

I don't mind changing my conception.

If you have any tips, suggestions, ...

Thanks and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Maybe a little more context into why there's a key store entity to edit (seemingly?) single-word text? If it's [translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html), that's one thing. If it's settings, a [Yaml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#using-the-symfony-yaml-component) treatment might be appropriate. Or an entity (maybe?) might be appropriate. Performance-wise, it doesn't seem like a great idea to put little single-word text snippets in their own row in a database, although again I don't know the implementation.

Comment: Ok I'll try. My website is composed by some texts like my presentation, what I'm actually working on, etc ... . I want these texts to be editable in sonata admin bundle. I've created an entity called EditableText(string key, string content) where I put as a key "presentation" and as a content "my text of presentation blablabla". Then in my controller I ask the database for the EditableText which has the "presentation" key and I get the content, and then I can load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your concept you can restrict access for an **editor** by using a role based security approach. You could grant the editor just the ROLES **LIST, VIEW, EDIT** as described in [the security section of the SonataAdminBundle documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#role-handler). This way the admin (you) can create the entities with the needed keys for your website and the editor could view and update them.

As an example: when you have defined your admin service as
`sonata.admin.editable_text`

you have to assign the roles

- `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_LIST`
- `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_VIEW`
- and `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_EDIT`

You could than easily group these roles into one role using the `role_hierarchy` directive of the `security` configuration:

```
security:
# ...
role_hierarchy:

    # group the roles for your convenience, 
    ROLE_SONATA_EDITOR:
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_LIST
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_VIEW
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_EDITABLE_TEXT_EDIT
```